# How do I put two values in the same input with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I put two values in an input with jquery?
I already made this code where I put the value of an input in the textarea, but I want it to put the value of the input along with a customized text.

Example:
Custom text: 'The value is' | Typed in the input: '10'

Final result within the textarea:
'The value is 10'

I don't know if I was specific, but whoever can help me thank you :)

```
$('.payOnDeliveryValor').change(function() {
    $('.woocommerce-input-wrapper textarea').val($('.payOnDeliveryValor').val());
});

<input class="payOnDeliveryValor" />

<div class="input-wrapper">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple string concatenation to join the custom text with the input value:

```
var custom_text = "The value is ";
$('.payOnDeliveryValor').change(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    if (text) text = custom_text + text;
    $('.woocommerce-input-wrapper textarea').val(text);
});
```